# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable in fmin numpy

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

i am trying to run the following script i have an error with (Fmin) i think. i have the following error:

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

thank you very much , i tried alot to solve it but i was not able ...Thanks again

```
   import numpy as n
   from scipy import optimize
        a=2
        b=3
        def f (ts):
            c= ts
            y= optimize.fmin(np.linalg.norm(a/c +b),x0=0.1)
            return y
        f2=np.vectorize(f)
        ts=np.linspace(1,50)

   print(f2(ts))
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for other `TypeError: ... is not callable` questions. This means you've made a programming error by passing a non-callable object somewhere that expects a callable object. In Python, "callable" generally means a function (or any object that accepts the `obj()` syntax. The `scipy.optimize` APIs typically take a function as their first argument, being the objective function you wish to optimize.

The expression `np.linalg.norm(a/b + c)` is not a function. You are simply evaluating the function on one argument and returning the result. It's not clear from your code which variable(s) you want to optimize for. Let's say it's `c` (with `a` and `b` fixed) (though you should really call it `x`--by convention it's common to use high letters in the Latin alphabet like `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` as independent variables, and low letters like `a`, `b`, `c` as constants--of course, this is highly context and domain specific). Then you might do

```
from np.linalg import norm
optimize.fmin(lambda x: norm(a/x + b), x0=0.01)
```

The `lambda x:` operator in this defines an in-line one argument function that implements your objective function on a single variable. Ｏf course, you can also optimize all of `a`, `b`, and `c` together as a vector. But you haven't specified what problem you're trying to solve, so I'll leave that as an exercise.

I should add, using `np.vectorize` the way you are is very slow. You can use `fmin` on an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
optimize.fmin()
```

takes in the first argument as a callable function but it is provided with a float64 object i.e. the return value of `np.linalg.norm(a/c +b)`

Comment: thanks , but what to do do to solve such a problem?

Comment: Checkout @Iguananaut answer below, she passed a lambda function as the first parameter. Moreover, try editing the code as it is not clear what's your goal in the code.